# App with menu - how to?

Tags: android, menu, connection

I need your help. I need to make an app as a school project. I made a splash screen and then on the activity_main.xml I wanted to make the menu. So I have written the code, a part of this is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black_24dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Admitere"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Conditii admitere specializarea IE"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Now I have to make it work, when I press click on the image it will open a new page. But I don't know how to make this connection. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You mean You want to open all pages in 1 frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an id to ImageView and make it onClicklistner in your java code.Use intent to go to another activity

Comment: So basically I need to make a different class for every activity? Because when it opens a new page I would like to put some info there

Comment: yes.every activity has its corresponding java code.